# Pandas groupby used with agg doesn't return key columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

In a project I'm working into I'm forced to use Pandas version 1.1.5.
I'm trying to do a group by operation in order to aggregate a variable using multiple functions:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame( { 
        "Name" : ["Alice", "Bob", "James", "Mallory", "Bob" , "Lucas", "Alice", "Bob", "James", "Mallory", "Bob" , "Lucas"] , 
        "Apples" : [22, 31, 35, 41, 27, 32, 64, 12, 59, 45, 65, 31] } )

apple_df = df.groupby('Name', as_index = False).agg(
    apple_avg = ('Apples', np.mean),
    apple_median = ('Apples', np.median),
    apple_count = ('Apples', np.count_nonzero)
)
apple_df
```

I'm expecting the *Name* column with the other aggregation variables as result like this:

[image]

But I'm getting the following:

[image]

Any known bug and workaround for this issue?

P.S.
All works fine with Pandas 1.3.0, but I can't use it in this project.

Comment: Just added the expected result

Comment: What happens if you remove the as_index and use .reset_index() at the end? Same output?

Comment: is named aggregation the problem?

Comment: @Andreas it works using .reset_index(). If you would add your answer, I'll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help, happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to remove the as_index parameter and make a .reset_index() instead:

```
apple_df = df.groupby('Name').agg(
    apple_avg = ('Apples', np.mean),
    apple_median = ('Apples', np.median),
    apple_count = ('Apples', np.count_nonzero)
).reset_index()
```